# How can I run a work service (BackgroundService) once a second?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

The following shows the scaffold-ed code when create a new **Worker Service** project using VS 2019/.Net 3.0.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    // ....

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Assuming this part takes 0.5 second
            // code omitted
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

I want the service to be run once a second. However, in the above code, assuming the code to be run before `Task.Delay` takes 0.5 second. The service will be triggered every 1.5 second instead of 1 second?

---

I know Timer can be used to trigger some actions. However, it seems the Worker service need to use `await Task.Delay(..., stoppingToken)` to release the execution. How can timer be used for **Worker Service** project (**BackgroundService**)?

Comment: What would you like to happen if `_logger.LogInformation` takes longer than 0.5 or over a second?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8 I think a timer might be a little more straightforward than hacking in the Task class.

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: @Dortimer even using a timer isn't sufficient alone, TBH, it's not just about what component to use; a timer and or a task, it doesn't matter, there's other obstacles in the way that *can* happen and still prevent the service from kicking off *every second*...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ not really. A timer ensures that the event will be called based on the configured Elapsed time. It doesn't matter if the code inside the event callback hasn't been fully processed, that event is called so long as the timer is running. `Task.Delay` will stop execution regardless. And `Task` isn't really the best way to go for this scenario.

Comment: You could use a timer, as others have suggested, or use a stopwatch to measure the elapsed time and subtract it from your desired wait. If the calculated remaining wait is greater than 0, then you delay, otherwise continue on to the next cycle.

Comment: @Dortimer what I was trying to say is, how can you guarantee that what ever logic has to run will complete in exactly less than one second before the next round comes around? If it's not complete, what should we do? I'm just saying it doesn't matter if you're using a timer, a task etc. all of it is irrelevant if you don't know how to handle your logic if it's not completed in the alloted time.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  You can easily use `Timer.Start()` and `Timer.Stop()` if you need to ensure the code executes before the elapsed time is hit, but I don't think that's what they're asking for.

Comment: @Dortimer I know Timer can be used to trigger some actions. However, it seems the Worker service need to use await `Task.Delay(..., stoppingToken)` to release the execution. How can timer be used for worker service?

Comment: @ca9163d9 This link should have the details for you to work through. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks